# Why is getting roles when getting a list of users so slow?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I'm getting all users in the DB and their associated roles. It works, but man is it slow.

```
        var ctx = new SiteUserContext();
        var ctxUserList = ctx.Users.ToList();


        //var userManager = new UserManager<SiteUser>(new UserStore<SiteUser>(new SiteUserContext()));

        var jsonModels = from user in ctxUserList
                         select new
                         {
                             userName = user.UserName,
                             Roles = (from userRole in user.Roles
                                      join role in ctx.Roles on userRole.RoleId
                                      equals role.Id
                                      select role.Name).ToList(),
                             id = user.Id
                         };
```

Getting just a list of users is fine, about 600ms for 100 users. But as soon as I try and add in the roles, I end up waiting 5-10 seconds. Each user only has 1 or 2 roles. This isn't exactly a huge query.

I tried using the userManager `GetRolesById(user.Id)` but that was even slower. 10+ seconds.

Any tips on making this run quickly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're doing a ToList on the roles. That's going to add an extra query for  each user. So you go from a single query to n queries where "n = number of users"

Comment: I typically try to keep this complex logic out of Linq. But I imagine you're going to want some sort of join.

Comment: Sounds like I may need to just use a stored procedure to do this quickly rather than relying on EF. Disappointing.

Comment: You should be able to use do it with EF/Linq. You just need to do a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is executing N+1 queries to get the information since you get the list of users, then enumerate the list of users to streamline.  Using LINQ we can do this a bit more efficiently.  I've used this before to do this in one process.

```
var usersWithRoles = (from user in ctx.Users  
                      select new  
                       {  
                        UserId = user.Id,                                        
                        Username = user.UserName,  
                        Email = user.Email,  
                        RoleNames = (from userRole in user.Roles  
                                     join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId   
                                     equals role.Id  
                                     select role.Name).ToList()  
                                  })
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(p => new   
                    {  
                       UserId = p.UserId,  
                       Username = p.Username,  
                       Email = p.Email,  
                       Role = string.Join(",", p.RoleNames)  
                    });
```

This should be much faster and get it with 1 query!

**Edit:** Looking at your request, if you just want the roles as a list, you can skip the second projection from this example.  (I had a need to display this in a list, thus the string.Join in the example.

Comment: That's not intuitive the way it handles that query when you try and split it out like I had it. You've done essentially the same thing, you just clumped the role part into the get users part. I would have assumed it would have still iterated over the users to get the roles. My assumption would have been two queries instead of one. Not 1 query vs N times.

Interesting, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @cphilpot Sadly this is one of the most common areas that is not fully understood with the way that EF runs due to the manner in which Deferred Execution works.  I'm glad that this got it working for you.  Its amazing how you can have a blazing fast change by making an incremental change.